# MVCxGridView Bind List<> with collection to column names

Tags: list, generics, gridview, model-view-controller, devexpress

i have some task: I have a List that I pass in View from Controller, But this model in itself is a collection. How should I bind a column in the method of constructing?

c#:

```
public static void GridColumns(List<ParameterCollection> model, MVCxGridViewColumnCollection columns)

    {
        columns.Add(??????????);

    }
```

View:

```
@model List<TFlex.DOCs.Model.Parameters.ParameterCollection>

@using TFlexDOCsWeb;


    @Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>

{
        settings.Name = "GridView";
        //settings.ClientSideEvents.Init = "OnInit"; 
        settings.KeyFieldName = "SystemFields.Id";
        settings.SettingsBehavior.ConfirmDelete = true;
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Catalogues", Action = "_GridViewPartial" };    
        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.Caption = "*";
        settings.CommandColumn.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(5);
        settings.SettingsPager.Visible = true;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = false;
        TFlexDOCsWeb.DevEx.GridViewBuilding.<bold>GridColumns</bold>(Model, settings.Columns);


        var headerFilterMode = true ? HeaderFilterMode.CheckedList : HeaderFilterMode.List;
        foreach (GridViewDataColumn column in settings.Columns)
            column.Settings.HeaderFilterMode = headerFilterMode;
        settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = true;
        settings.Settings.ShowFilterRowMenu = true;

    }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()<bold>
</bold>
```

model ParameterCollection consist from , where parameter.Value = is value, and parameter.ParameterInfo = Caption of this parameter(name of field). I Dont know how to bind column names for each ParameterCollection Parameter.parameterInfo.name

Answer (score 0):

You just bind it to the name of the property on the object(s) that your list holds in the column settings where you make your gridviewsettings.
See below simplified example.

MODEL

```
namespace Some.Name.Space
{
    public class RecipientListViewModel : List<RecipientViewModel>  // HOwever you define your list
    {
    }

    public class RecipientViewModel
    {
        public string Id {get; set;}
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

VIEW

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        //General settings
        settings.Name = "GridViewName";
        settings.KeyFieldName = "Id"; // actual parameter name of keyfield on your object that is in your list
        //other settings etc



        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.Name = "FullName"; // actual parameter name on your object that is in your list that you want on the column
            column.FieldName = "FullName"; // actual parameter name on your object that is in your list that you want on the column
            column.Caption = LanguageHelper.GetText("UserConfig_Recipients_RecipientNameHeader"); 
            //column.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(200);
        });
        //other columns etc
}).Bind(YourModel).GetHtml()
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Overview()
{
    RecipientListViewModel model = PopulateInformationView(); // Populates the list with data 
    return View("YOURVIEWNAME", model);
}
```